# Get Cookie By Key?

Tags: python

Is there way to get a cookie by key when using `Cookielib`?

```
# Initalize the CookieJar
cookieJar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener    = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookieJar))

# Visit page, cookies are set here
req       = urllib2.Request("https://example.com")
resp      = opener.open(req)  
csrfToken = getCSRFToken(resp.read())
```

The cookies are set in the response, but how do I access and individual cookie by it's key?

I'm using Python 2.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) . It's a really simple library that will do just what you asked.

```
url = 'http://example.com/some/cookie/setting/url'
r = requests.get(url)
r.cookies['example_cookie_name']
```

Comment: I've recently discovered requests, and I have to say it's pretty awesome.